# Excel com Fórmula condicional ao mês

Tags: microsoft-excel, fórmula

Eu tenho esta fórmula na coluna de calculo na tabela:
`=+(K5+L5)*(1+8%)` funcionando!

Alterei o calculo condicionado ao mês, exemplo:
=`IF(MONTH(A4)>=10,(+(K4+L4)*(1+10%)),(+(K4+L4)*(1+8%)))` funcionou!

#### Pergunta:

Como usar o AND corretamente?

`=IF((MONTH(A4)<=2) AND (MONTH(A4)>=10)    ,(+(K4+L4)*(1+10%)),(+(K4+L4)*(1+8%)))`

> Obs. A data na célula A4 está neste formato:
>
> Ano/Mês/Dia - 2019/02/04

Comment: Assim: `IF(AND(MONTH(A4)<=2,MONTH(A4)>=10)...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua fórmula contém algumas coisas erradas, por exemplo, aqueles `+` soltos na fórmula e o uso errado do `and`.

Para usar um `and` ou `or` corretamente você tem que colocá-los no início da função que eles irão concatenar, no seu caso logo após o `if`. Ficaria assim:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(A4)<=2,MONTH(A4)>=10),(K4+L4)*(1+10%),(K4+L4)*(1+8%))
```

Confira um excelente tutorial sobre o assunto [clicando aqui](https://www.aprenderexcel.com.br/2014/tutoriais/funcao-ou).

Comment: Uso o Office 365 em inglês no trabalho (onde testei a fórmula acima) e o Office 365 em casa e em ambos uso o `;`. Mas isso pode ser alterado. Caso seja do interesse, só seguir esse passo a passo https://www.officetooltips.com/office_2016/tips/change_the_semicolon_to_a_comma_or_vice_versa.html

Comment: Max e Ricardo, obrigado. Coloquei a formula, porem não funcionou no meu Excel 2010 japonês!

Comment: Alterei a formula e funcionou!

Max e Ricardo formula:
=IF(AND(MONTH(A4)<=2,MONTH(A4)>=10),(K4+L4)*(1+10%),(K4+L4)*(1+8%))
Alterada.
=IF(AND(MONTH(A4)>=4,MONTH(A4)<=10),(+(K4+L4)*(1+10%)),(+(K4+L4)*(1+8%)))     
Resolvido! 
Moderador como aceitar a resposta neste caso?

Comment: @soushinsha Leia [como aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)